# dataframe sample data until I have N different values in 1 column

Tags: python, pandas, random

I need to sample data until I have N different values in 1 column

for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,2,3,2,3,2,3,1,4,5,3,4,5,2,3,2], columns=['col'])
```

a possible result for N=3 can be:

```
[1,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

or:

```
[1,2,4,1,2,4,2,1,1,1,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`set(df['col'].values)` will give you unique values in a column.

Then use `list-comprehension` to filter the values.

```
import random
N = 3
x = random.sample(set(df['col'].values), N)  

op = [i for idx, i in df['col'].iteritems() if i in x]
print(op)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3]
```